# DIY Google home using PC and BT speaker with mic

Tags: python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk

I have this BT speaker , with in built mic , http://www.intex.in/speakers/bluetooth-speakers/it-11s-bt
i want to build something like google home with it , using python .Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of issues with using a bluetooth speaker & mic combo on the raspberry pi. Most people have an issue getting the mic to work. [This thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=148832) discusses some of the issues. [This extensive post](http://youness.net/raspberry-pi/bluetooth-headset-raspberry-pi-3-ad2p-hsp) describes needing a bluetooth dongle

You may be better off using it as a speaker and then [buying a separate mic](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01D4O75MO/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

Then just connect the blutooth speaker to the pi (from the top right of the screen) and plug in the microphone and run through [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/).

Answer (score 0):

I've read a couple articles and comments that suggest the reason why bluetooth is not an ideal setup is because BT and WIFI both use the same 2.4 Ghz band and slow each other down / disconnect when used simultaneously. My advice would be to do what I did: run a usb mic with an extension cable from inside a cabinet or entertainment unit and connect it to your audio system or run a 3.5 mm headphone jack extension too.

I've been writing [a tutorial that is for beginners](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E26n8fu0OmfGb6f7grQ0CRu76Yvyhk9B6clUhFtnQwQ/edit) and is super easy to follow. All the steps to get it up and running (step 3) and monitor-free (step 4) are there.

I'll be working on it throughout the summer, adding the LED support, similar to G Home. Best of luck!